# A "speedometer" that doesn't use GPS

Tags: android, iphone, gps, smartphone

How to calculate speed without requiring GPS? I have heard of something called "sensor technology" but am not sure what that means. I am asking because I want to make an app, but I don't think it is battery efficient to use GPS, plus it is for a long-term project so I want the app to continuously run without having to manually turn it on or turn on GPS.

Comment: [Pounding a Nail: Old shoe or glass bottle?](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever- nice link. I've been illustrating this point with the story the guy tied up in a trunk, trying to determine where he is and how fast the car is moving based on the bumps on the road. Not an easy task

Answer (score 4):

GPS is by far the most accurate way to do this.

You can get access to the accelerometers, but they are not remotely accurate enough for this type of application.

The only other way I can think of would be to get one of those bluetooth adapters that you plug into your car's diagnostic port, and get the speedometer input from there.  Then, you're wasting power on bluetooth as well.

Just buy a power adapter for your phone to run on the vehicle.

Comment: Also, your acceleration would be zero relative to your vehicle, correct?

Comment: @aquinas, Yes, but why should that matter?  You accelerate with your vehicle.

Comment: Because he wants a *speedometer.* The accelerometer can't tell you how fast you are currently going, because its current acceleration will be zero because its velocity will be constant.

Comment: @aquinas, You're telling me that you sit in your car and never accelerate?  You can't move without accelerating.  Think this through before trying to make some ridiculous claim.  In any case, as I said, accelerometers in phones are no where near accurate enough to provide useful data.  If you had an accurate accelerometer, you can very well determine the speed difference from where you started and any point in time thereafter.  Since you start  your car from not moving, you determine the speed.

Comment: "You're telling me that you sit in your car and never accelerate?" No, I'm saying if you have been traveling at 65 MPH for the past 10 minutes, at any time during those past 10 minutes, you haven't been accelerating, correct?

Comment: @aquinas, That's correct.  The idea would be that you enable the app before you start moving.  Otherwise, obviously there would be no acceleration.

Comment: Also, the accelerometer would pick up vibrations caused by bumps on the road. Here's some real-world data: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56238/accelerometer-data-smoothing-filtering-pothole-detection

Answer (score 4):

I tried to measure the speed using Android's **accelerometer sensor** for an indoor-navigation project but that failed miserably. I intented to derive the current speed from the acceleration/deceleration over time and so in the end calculate movements along the X, Y and Z-axis, but that didn't work out at all. The accelerometer sensors of common Android devices are way too inaccurate for that kind of usage.

So, you will have to use GPS. To reduce battery drain, you can increase the intervals (time and/or distance) in which the `LocationManager` notifies your App. See the minTime and minDistance parameters of it's [requestLocationUpdates()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

Android allows you to use cellular phone antennas and wi-fi access point antennas as reference points to determine your current location without using the GPS (see: [locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER)).

Once determined your position in two different moments/points you can easily calculate your speed in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one can calculate speed without the assistance of GPS. Speed depends on distance and time. I am not sure if we can calculate distance just like that. 
Anyway look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html
There we have different sensor types. Perhaps you can make use of one of those.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are referring to would be considered "dead reckoning" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning) and is possible, but will lead to drift and incorrect speed information, especially if the user of your app doesn't have the device mounted securely to whatever is moving.

Would it be a valid use case for your app to go to sleep and turn off the GPS? You might be able to devise a way to turn the GPS back on when you bring the app out of suspension. If you need the location always, then GPS is your best bet. People understand that GPS based apps require power and will come up with a way to plug it in to use it long term.

Perhaps you should think about the use cases for your app and ask if people are willing to drain their battery power for whatever functionality you will offer.

Answer (score 0):

Using acceleration and time you can calculate change in velocity but you don't necessarily know the starting velocity. Plus the accelerometer in an iPhone probably isn't accurate enough for this anyway, but it's not a bad shout.